# VLOOKUP giving #N/A and I have no idea why

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function, excel-match

[image]

Why doesn't this work? I tried checking for whitespace, made sure length was the same, etc. Driving me nuts! I just want Alabama! The error given is "Value not available".

Comment: the order of your column is wrong. The leftmost column must contain the value you are matching. what you are doing is looking for `AL` in the `State Name` column. of course, excel can't see it and thus returns `#N/A!`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual solution is to apply =MATCH to find the row number in the array:

```
=MATCH(D1,B:B,0)
```

will search for the value in `D1` in ColumnB (the last `0` means exactly) and hopefully return `2` (the second row in the chosen array - ie the whole of ColumnB). This can then be fed into:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(D1,B:B,0))
```

where it becomes the second row of ColumnA, ie `Alabama`

Details here [=MATCH](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/match-HP005209168.aspx)  [=INDEX](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/match-function-HP010342679.aspx) and also  http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2011/03/the-imposing-index.html

Comment: plus one for explanation and tutorial links :D

Comment: I used to have a sticky note on my monitor that said `=index(range, row, column)` and `Match(what,row or column, 0 for exact or 1 for nearest)`. That helped internalise the syntax and wean me off Offset().

Comment: @pnuts there is no need to delete. As what Tim Williams said, having the same answer is not a waste but rather a way to show the OP that the presented solution is indeed true and correct.

Answer (score 4):

The order of your column is wrong. The leftmost column must contain the value you are matching. What you are doing is looking for ***AL*** in the *State Name* column. Of course, excel can't see it and thus returns `#N/A!`.

You can try this:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(D1,$B:$B,0),1)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1, but also note that in a range with just one column or just one row, Index works fine without the third parameter. If the range is a column, just do =index(column, number). If the range is a row, then just do =index(row, number). The third parameter is only required in a range with several columns AND several rows. Then the second parameter specifies the row and the third parameter the column.

Comment: @teylyn is right. The reason why i completed the syntax is for the OP to get a hang of the formula. :D btw, pnuts provided a complete explantion and link on how to use the functions.

Answer (score 0):

The formula looks for "AL" in the first column specified (column A). It only finds "Alabama", so returns error.

Comment: I see. How would you suggest I get Alabama then without switching the columns around? I appreciate it.

Comment: You can use a combination of `match` and `offset`. `match` finds the row of interest, and then you `offset` by that many rows.

Comment: @TidusSmith or you can use `INDEX and MATCH` combination. See my post.

Comment: =OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(D1,$B$2:$B$2,0),0)

Comment: see [THIS](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm) in support on @pnuts statement.

Comment: interesting... something new to learn about Excel. Thanks for the feedback (and especially the link).

Answer (score 0):

It can be slightly easier, even:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(D1,B:B))
```

Comment: Agreed. To insist on exact match, then use =INDEX(A:A,MATCH(D1,B:B,0))