# Excel VLOOKUP is not working

Tags: excel, vba

Excel `VLOOKUP` is not working though I have followed exact syntax.

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,A1:B5,1,FALSE)
```

returns `#N/A`

[image]

Comment: You are searching the first column (`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`) for `a`

Comment: possible duplicate of [VLOOKUP giving #N/A and I have no idea why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618359/vlookup-giving-n-a-and-i-have-no-idea-why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
=INDEX(A1:A5,MATCH(C1,B1:B5,0))
```

returns `1` which I assume is what you want.

In fact, I would suggest (almost) always using this `INDEX`-`MATCH` combo rather than `VLOOKUP`. It's much more flexible.

Comment: what if multiple matches found ? will it throw first matched one ?

Comment: The answer is in [Excel help for `MATCH`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/match-HP005209168.aspx).