# I need help looking for a value and return value of cell to the right in excel

Tags: excel

i am having a problem with the lookup function in excel. i need to look through a column and get a return value from data in the same row but column to the right.

ie

1 | bob |

3 | jim |

7 | lis |

i want to search for the value 1 then return the name bob

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the "problem" you are having with the lookup function, exactly? Have you tried using it in any way?

Comment: yes i have, it gives me a n/a error, however when i fix that it gives me a name error even when i copy examples from microsofts website.

Comment: Well, what's the function that you are trying?

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257424/excel-vlookup-is-not-working/24257502#24257502

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use vlookups, Index, Match is recommended.  Here is a great explanation. 
http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/

The formula to find the name associate with "1" becomes:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1,A:A,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

=VLOOKUP(1,A:B,2,FALSE)

Go into help file and read about VLOOKUP for more details.